# Why does ajax POST work but GET doesn't with Rails json request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, post

I am having understanding how ajax works with Rails. I have a method where depending on what option is selected in an html select, I load another select with the value of the first select. These selects are in a _partial if that matters. I cannot get the controller to print any of my 'puts' statements when I use GET and the response is ". Error string: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <. Status: parsererror". But then miraculously when I change it to POST everything works.

Here is the route:

```
get '/mycontroller/get_list_with_ajax'
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/mycontroller/get_list_with_ajax",
    data: {
        "groupName": groupName,
        "authenticity_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: constants.AJAX_TIMEOUT,
    cache: false,
    success:function(result) {
    ...
```

Controller:

```
  def get_list_with_ajax
     puts "HELLO!"
     ...
     result = { 'response' => 'SUCCESS',
                'more_options' => ['example'] }
     render :json => result
  end
```

EDIT: I notice when I use POST the response content type is 'application/json' and GET sets it to 'text/html. I have tried all 3 of:

```
 response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
 response.content_type = 'application/json'
 render :json => result, :content_type => 'application/json'
```

But none of them change the result in the Chrome console or with curl -LI . No idea why.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: try to add `headers: {"Content-type: application/json"}` after `type: "GET",`

Comment: @RailsOuter hmm no dice. Console keeps complaining about: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: try with {"Accept": "application/json"} for get request.

Comment: perhaps your content is too large or contain some special chars

Comment: Do you get the same error if you go directly to localhost/mycontroller/get_list_with_ajax with the same GET parameters you used? If so then problem is not the AJAX, next if you comment out everything after `puts "HELLO!"` and see if that works. If it does, it may be something in the controller or if not, it may be something in your get parameters as Ilyas suggested.

Comment: I commented with my workaround in an answer

Answer (score 0):

My work around was to move the rails methods into a different controller. I moved them to /a_different_controller/get_list_with_ajax and it worked. Why? I don't know.

I tried with headers: {"Accept": "application/json}, the GET url didn't contain any special characters, just a string and the auth token,
groupName=MY-GROUP&authenticity_token=QqbP57iTw.....

If someone with more Rails experience than I wants to comment that would be great.

Comment: You can't send json using GET, json has to be part of the packet contents. Which is why your PUT succeeds. GET puts all the values in the url, for example `my_url?x=1&y=2&z=3`. This is not a json structure.